# Save lat long from Places API on Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, google-places-api

I want to use the Places API and extract the lat and long and save it into sharedpreferences in Flutter. There is some other information as well which I want to save as well.

I am unable to save lat and lng, but able to save others. What is it that I am missing.

Below is the code I have for saving. The context of the SaveData is not able to access inside of getPlaceDetailWithLatLng. Any ideas?

```
class _UserProfileState extends State<UserProfile> {

  TextEditingController textnamecontroller = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController dateinput = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController placecontroller = TextEditingController();

  //text editing controller for text field

  @override
  void initState() {
    timeinput.text = ""; //set the initial value of text field
    dateinput.text = ""; //set the initial value of text field
    super.initState();
  }

  //text editing controller for text field

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child : SafeArea(
            child: Center(
              child: Card(
            elevation: 20.0,
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(),
                  child: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                  child: Column(

                    children: <Widget>[
                      SizedBox(
                        height: MediaQuery
                            .of(context)
                            .size
                            .height * 0.05,
                      ),
                      Container(
                        child: (
                            //              Card(
                            //                child :
                            Text('Welcome!', )
                            //             )
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: MediaQuery
                            .of(context)
                            .size
                            .height * 0.02,
                      ),
                      Card(
                          child: TextField(
                            controller: textnamecontroller,
                            maxLength: 40,
                            buildCounter: null,
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                                counterText: "",
                                icon: Icon(Icons.perm_identity),
                                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)
                                ),
                                hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue),
                                labelText: "Name",
                                hintText: "Enter your name"
                            ),
                          )
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: MediaQuery
                            .of(context)
                            .size
                            .height * 0.02,
                      ),
                      Card(
                          child: TextField(
                            controller: dateinput,
                            //editing controller of this TextField
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)
                                ),
                                icon: Icon(Icons.calendar_today),
                                //icon of text field
                                labelText: "Registration Date" //label text of field
                            ),
                            readOnly: true,
                            //set it true, so that user will not able to edit text
                            onTap: () async {
                              DateTime? pickedDate = await showDatePicker(
                                  context: context,
                                  initialDate: DateTime.now(),
                                  firstDate: DateTime(1900),
                                  //DateTime.now() - not to allow to choose before today.
                                  lastDate: DateTime(2101)
                              );

                              if (pickedDate != null) {
                                print(
                                    pickedDate); //pickedDate output format => 2021-03-10 00:00:00.000
                                String formattedDate = DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd')
                                    .format(pickedDate);
                                print(
                                    formattedDate); //formatted date output using intl package =>  2021-03-16
                                //you can implement different kind of Date Format here according to your requirement

                                setState(() {
                                  dateinput.text =
                                      formattedDate; //set output date to TextField value.
                                });
                              } else {
                                print("Date is not selected");
                              }
                            },
                          )
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: MediaQuery
                            .of(context)
                            .size
                            .height * 0.02,
                      ),
                      
                      SizedBox(
                        height: MediaQuery
                            .of(context)
                            .size
                            .height * 0.02,
                      ),
                      Card(
                        child: placesAutoCompleteTextField(),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: MediaQuery
                            .of(context)
                            .size
                            .height * 0.02,
                      ),
                      ElevatedButton(onPressed: () async {
                        print(await saveText());
                      }, child: Text(' Save Data'))

                    ],
                  )),
            )))));
  }

  placesAutoCompleteTextField() {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
      child: GooglePlaceAutoCompleteTextField(
          textEditingController: placecontroller,
          googleAPIKey: "<<APIKey>>",
          inputDecoration: InputDecoration(
              hintText: "Location",
              labelText: "Start typing"),
          debounceTime: 800,

 //         countries: ["in", "fr"],
          isLatLngRequired: true,
          getPlaceDetailWithLatLng: (Prediction prediction) async {
            print("placeDetails" + prediction.lng.toString());
            print("place lat long"+ prediction.lat.toString()+"  "+prediction.lng.toString());

            String latitude = prediction.lat.toString();
            String longitude = prediction.lng.toString();

            SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
            await prefs.setString("latitude", latitude);
            await prefs.setString("longitude", longitude);

            prefs.commit();

  //          return (latitude,longitude);

//            saveText();

          },
          itmClick: (Prediction prediction) {
            placecontroller.text = prediction.description!;

          //  placecontroller. = prediction.lat!;


            placecontroller.selection = TextSelection.fromPosition(
                TextPosition(offset: prediction.description!.length));
          }
        // default 600 ms ,
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<bool> saveText() async{
    String name = textnamecontroller.text;
    String location = placecontroller.text.toString();
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    await prefs.setString('name', name);
    await prefs.setString('location', location);
 // latitude
 // longitude
    print(prefs.getString(name)!);
    print(prefs.getString(birthplace)!);

    return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: When you say "I am unable to save", do you get an error or?..

Comment: I dont get the value outside of that function. I get error while trying to do so.